# ¿Cómo abrir la pantalla de permiso para una aplicación específica en Android M?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-m

¿Se puede abrir la pantalla de información en ajustes del dispositivo  de una aplicación especifica o bien lo más cercano posible?

Solo debe ser compatible en Android 6+

Comment: te refieres a la pantalla donde puedes borrar caché y datos de la aplicación, desinstalar la app y ves la información?

Comment: @joc Si esa pantalla, o bien si está en Android M, a la sección permisos si es posible

Comment: Acabo de encontrar lo siguiente me falta comprobarlo para que sea una respuesta veraz, si alguien lo puede corrobar creando una respuesta de  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando la información, se puede abrir la sección de Configuración del dispositivo:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

o la configuración de la aplicación :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).setData(Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)));
```

en donde podremos acceder a configurar los permisos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desgraciadamente hasta el día de hoy [Android N, API 23](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html) no es posible acceder directamente a los permisos.

En el sitio en [inglés agregué una respuesta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498667/250260).

Answer (score 3):

Basado en la respuesta de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android)

No hay forma para abrir la sección de permisos de la app dentro de ajustes del sistema, pero lo más cercano es poder abrir la sección `información de la aplicación` ver imágen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Función startInstalledAppDetailsActivity**

```
public static void startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(final Activity context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    final Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Su uso llamar la función pasando un `context`

```
startInstalledAppDetailsActivity(this);
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta correcta!, no estoy seguro si los Flags son importantes ya que la pantalla de configuración de la aplicación se abre como nueva Activity.

Comment: Agrega esta como la respuesta correcta, la mia es solo complemento de la información, saludos!.

Comment: Buenas, así ya queda cerrada, y está mucho más detallado ^_^